# Which yum variable can give 6 or 7 as output

Tags: yum, rhel

I can see the yum variables as on Redhat page at [Redhat docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Using_Yum_Variables.html)

The variable $releasever resolves to 6Server or 7Server etc

Is there any default variable which can resolve to just 6 or 7

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For RedHat `6Server` and `7Server` *are* the values that matter as far as I know.

I don't believe `6` and `7` don't mean anything in RH land (they do for CentOS though).

So I would doubt that there's anything built in for them.

But you can add a custom variable yourself easily enough by dropping a file in `/etc/yum/vars/` and using its name as the variable.

So `echo 6 > /etc/yum/vars/barever` and then use `$barever` in the yum configuration.